# How do I call out to a specific model version with Python and a TensorFlow serving model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a few machine learning models running via TensorFlow Serving on Kubernetes. I'd like to be able to have one deployment of a particular model, and then load multiple versions.

This seems like it would be easier than having to maintain a separate Kubernetes deployment for each version of each model that we have.

But it's not obvious how to pass the version or model flavor I want to call using the Python gRPC interface to TF Serving. How do I specify the version and pass it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, it's not possible to update the model spec in place as you're building the request to pull. Instead, you need to separately build an instance of `ModelSpec` that includes the version you want, and then pass that in to the constructor for the prediction request.

Also worth pointing out you need to use the Google-specific `Int64Value` for the version.

```
from google.protobuf.wrappers_pb2 import Int64Value
from tensorflow_serving.apis.model_pb2 import ModelSpec
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2, get_model_metadata_pb2, \
                                    prediction_service_pb2_grpc
from tensorflow import make_tensor_proto
import grpc

model_name = 'mymodel'
input_name = 'model_input'
model_uri = 'mymodel.svc.cluster.local:8500'

X = # something that works

channel = grpc.insecure_channel(model_uri, options=MESSAGE_OPTIONS)
stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

version = Int64Value(value=1)
model_spec = ModelSpec(version=version, name=model_name, signature_name='serving_default')

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest(model_spec=model_spec)
request.inputs[input_name].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto(X.astype(np.float32), shape=X.shape))
result = stub.Predict(request, 1.0)
channel.close()
```